# CSS: strange behaviour with position absolute (elements moving)

Tags: css, css-position

I use several **div blocks** on my website with position relative. Inside them I put blocks with position absolute. However, first time in my life I noticed such a strange behaviour. At least in Opera those blocks **which have position absolute** start to move up and down (not staying in one place), when I scroll up and down the page or when I mouseover the Magic Zoom plugin. If I set for instance top: 0px; and left: 0px; they stay at the same place. Maybe I changed something in the code, because this stuff started to happen only recently.

```
<div class="innerWrapper" style="width: 100%; position: relative">
    <div class="inside" style="left: auto; 
        right: auto; 
        bottom: auto; 
        top: -24px; 
        position: absolute;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can show your code or any example?

Comment: May be problem in Magic Zoom plugin? Does it support Opera?

Comment: I have tried to switch Magic Zoom off , but it made no changes.

Comment: Please create [testcase](https://www.google.com/search?q=testcase) of your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score -3):

Put your absolute div right after the parent div. The absolute div should be first child of your relative div.

Comment: You are not right. The absolute div **not** should be **first** child of your relative div, absolute divs may be **everywhere** in parent div.